# How to include titles in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, subfiles

I have a bit of an odd request––but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. I have compiled one main document that includes multiple subfiles by way of the `subfile` package. Here are MWEs:

Main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subfile{doc1}
\subfile{doc2}

\end{document}
```

Example subfile, e.g., `doc1.tex`:

```
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author 1}
\maketitle

\section{Doc 1 Section}
Text
```

Here's what I would like: a table of contents that only lists the title for each subfile.

Given the number of subfiles I have, any solution that requires me to make some sort of manual edit to each subfile is impractical (e.g., changing the `\title{}` to another command).

I started using the `subfiles` package when I didn't fully understand it, and at the time I didn't intend to have a ToC, so I perfectly understand if there is not a solution to this problem––at least, not a solution with the simplicity that I would like.

Comment: I don't know how the subfile pakcage works or why you would want to use it since \include and \includonly would do the job just fine.

Comment: I think it was because the subfiles package allows the subfiles to use the preamble of the main file––but \include may allow that, too. I'm not sure. In any event, would I be able to accomplish what I'd like if I had done \include instead? Could I have a TOC with only the \title{} of each included document? Just curious for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code inserts the `\title` for each `\subfile` into the ToC as a "`\chapter`". This is just to avoid the conflict of inserting regular `\section`s as well (you didn't request that, but it could be accommodated).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{doc1.tex}
\title{Doc1}
\author{Author 1}
\maketitle

\section{Doc 1 Section}
Text
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{doc2.tex}
\title{Doc2}
\author{Author 2}
\maketitle

\section{Doc 2 Section}
Text
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{titling}% Allows for multiple \titles within one document
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% Remove \section from ToC

\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \oldmaketitle
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thetitle}%
}
\makeatletter
\let\l@chapter\l@section
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\z@}{\m@ne}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subfile{doc1}
\subfile{doc2}

\end{document}
```

The formatting of the `\title` entry in the ToC is similar to the regular `\section` formatting, even though it's technically inserted as a `\chapter`.

Comment: Appears to have worked! The solution is a little more complex than I had imagined, so I appreciate your help. I will probably make a few more tweaks, but definitely, the basic structure I needed is there.